# Can a SQL Case statment be used to test if a Join statement should be used?

Tags: sql, select, join, nested, case

What I am trying to do, using java, is:

- access a database
- read a record from table "Target_stats"
- if the field "threat_level" = 0, doAction1
- if the field "threat_level" > 0, get additional fields from another table "Attacker_stats" and doAction2
- read the next record

Now I have everything I need but a well thought out SQL statement that will allow me to only go through the database only once, if this does not work I suspect I will need to use two separate SQL statements and go through the database a second time. I do not have a clear understanding of case statements, so I will just provide pseudo code using an if statement.

```
SELECT A.1, A.2, A.3
   if(A.3 > 0){
      SELECT A.1, A.2, A.3, B.1, B.3 
      FROM A 
      JOIN B 
      ON A.1 = B.1
      }
FROM A
```

Can anyone shed any light on my situation?

EDIT: Thankyou both for your time and effort. I understand both of your comments and I believe that I am headed more towards the right direction however, I'm still having some trouble. I didn't know about SQLfiddle before so I have now gone ahead and made a sample DB and tried to demonstrate my purpose. Here is the link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ea108/1  What I want to do here is Select target_stats.server_id, target_stats.target, target_stats.threat_level Where interval_id=3 and if the threat_level>0 I want to retrieve attack_stats.attacker, attack_stats.sig_name Where interval_id=3.  Again, thankyou for your time and effort it is very useful to me

EDIT: after some tinkering around, I figured it out. thankyou so much for your help

Comment: SQL is *not* procedural code. If there are two different "actions" as you state, your intent may be clearer to someone reading your code if there are two distinct queries. I don't know how complex these queries are, but if they are as simple as the example suggests, the db hit probably won't even make a noticeable performance difference. Purely speculation, but just a thought...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ocelot20 said, SQL is *not* procedural code. It is based on set-based operations, not per row operations. One immediate consequence of this is that the `SELECT` in your pseudo-example is wrong as it relies on rows in the same result set having different column lists.

That said, you can get pretty close to your pseudo-code example, if you can tolerate `NULL` values where the join is not possible.

Here's an example that (to me anyway) seems to be close to what your are driving at:

```
select *
from A 
  left outer join B 
    on A.a = B.d and A.a > 2
```

You can see it in action in [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7d3db/3), which should show you what sort of output to expect.

Note that what this is actually saying is something like this:

> Fetch all the records from table `A` and also fetch any records from
>   table `B` have their `d` column the same as the `a` column in table
>   `A`, provided the value of `A.a` is greater than 2.

(This was picked for convenience. In my rather contrived example shifting the conditional column does not effect the output as can be see [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7d3db/4)).